# How to prove Sorgenfrey topology stronger than standard?

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

I understand that my title's statement is true and I'm not sure why. Any [a,b) set is open on Sorgenfrey's so I guess I could use a union of all [a + 1/n, b) sets in order to get the (a,b) set which is open on the standard topology.

Is that correct?

But, if this is true, then why not union all [a, b+1/n) sets in order to get the set [a,b] and thus prove [a,b] is also open on Sorgenfrey topology. I'm confused...

thx

Comment: Because the union of $[a,b+1/n)$ over all $n$ is not $[a,b]$. The intersection, however, is equal to the closed interval. But then again, an infinite intersection of open sets need not be open.

Comment: By the way, if $[a,b]$ were open, we'd have $[x-1,x]\cap[x,x+1]=\{x\}$ being open, which would give us the discrete topology.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus yeah, I know that. That what triggered my question since I knew Sorgenfrey != disc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $[a,b]$ is equal to the intersection $$[a,b] =\bigcap_n \left[ a, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ not the union $$\bigcup_n \left[ a, b+\frac{1}{n}\right) .$$